# ionic 3 geolocation not working on real device

Tags: ionic3

Geo location Code for ionic :

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then( pos =>{

      this.lat = pos.coords.latitude;     
      this.long = pos.coords.longitude;
}).catch(err => this.presentToast(err));
```

Comment: Need more Information, Please Share your ionic details and Plugin details.

Comment: I am using @ionic-native/geolocation plugin and ionic 3

Comment: did you allow location permission on device?

Comment: yes I   am allow location permission

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: its work on browser and when i am debug android device using data cable it working fine but when i am install .apk in my device then it not working . not getting any error message

Comment: Where are you doing this? Did you try on platform.ready()?

Comment: @Najamussaqib: sir its also not working for me actually i don't receive success callback or error callback from the function tell me sir what's the problem?

Comment: @Kapilsoni share your code..

Comment: @Najamussaqib :sir In which section we have put my code?

Comment: create https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

1)  we have to install a compatible version of the plugin, in my case it was
`"@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.4.2"`,

2) we have to put it in the `packaje.json` denpendencies
   just copy this version to the packaje in my case it was 4.4.2

3) we have to run this cmd to take off node_modules after reinstall it like that
     `rm -rf node_modules/`

4) after you have to clean the cache before to install
     `npm cache clean --force`

5) now reinstall the node_module by running this cmd command
   `npm install`

6) in my case i m using visual studio IDE i had problem with storage,i resolved with
a lil trick but i don't know  why, just take off the storage with `ctrl + x` and put it back again `ctrl + v`. and ready to use my app.

and one morething in ur mobile you have to give the gps permission to be able to use it.

hope this help you